# Update database with value from datetimepicker

Tags: c#, datetime, data-binding, picker

Using Visual Studio 2010 and c#, I created a windows form and dragged text fields from the data sources tree to the form.

The fields display fine and when I change the text in one of them and press the save button, it gets saved to the database.

I put a datetimepicker on the form and under properties->databindings->value I selected the field from my database.

When I open the form the datetime picker loads the correct date from the database. But when I CHANGE the date using the datetime picker and then press the SAVE button, the date doesn't change in the database.

Am I missing something?

Comment: furthermore - when I change the value in the datetime picker, I can no longer select any of the other text fields on the form - application effectively crashed and has to be closed.

Comment: Can you share some of your code pls.